# feature convert to geoJSON string failed

Tags: openlayers-3

I got a geometry from FeatureOverlay,and create a feature from this geometry, when I setId and setGeometryName to the feature ,I will be failed to writeFeature , is this a bug ?

```
var poly = featureOverlay.getFeatures().item(0);
        if (poly != null) {

            var feature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: poly
            });
            feature.setId('bd355df3fd916d30');
            feature.setGeometryName('test');
            var extent = [0, 0, 749, 638];
            var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
                code: 'xkcd-image',
                units: 'pixels',
                extent: extent
            });
            var geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                defaultDataProjection: projection
            });

           //this will be success
            var geoJSONText = geoJSON.writeFeature(poly, {
                featureProjection: projection,
                dataProjection: projection
            });
           //this will be failed
           var geoJSONText = geoJSON.writeFeature(feature, {
                featureProjection: projection,
                dataProjection: projection
           });
        }



Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
l.qd @ openlayers?v=YGwTOEaGf-vdYCn0EwOqEIY8JyARvCDFTRAySewZwRI1:501
stopInteraction @ testedit?id=8b0d3745a6c1b46b:447
onclick @ testedit?id=8b0d3745a6c1b46b:230
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my problem.

```
feature.setId('bd355df3fd916d30');
feature.setGeometryName('test');
```

modified to this will be fixed :

```
feature.setId('bd355df3fd916d30');
feature.setProperties(['test']);
```